# Is there a way to include matplotlib and a file selector within screen manager in Kivy. I am new to coding any help is appreciated

Tags: python, file, matplotlib, kivy

I am trying to incorporate matplotlib as a page and fileviewer as a page. I understand the fileviewer build is referenced but not defined. I am a little lost on how to incorporate it into the code. I spend way too much time debugging and fighting this. Any help is appreciated. [image: ScreenManager]

I tried defining the file viewer in the code but it either doesn't change that when a file is selected it crashes or it completely makes the app unstable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use matplotlib graph in window of kivy, you can use image of graph.

```
plt.savefig('testplot.png')
```

Try to use this file in kivy